# How can i use asterisk(*) in command line arguments in groovy?

Tags: regex, groovy, command-line, arguments, syntax-error

Helo!

I've a groovy script with one argument. The argument has to be a regex pattern. I want to use an * in the argument, but always got: **The syntax of the command is incorrect.**

This is an example (opt.p is the pattern getting from the arg):

```
    def map1 = [e:'pine___apple', f:'pineapple']
    map1.each { entry ->
                entry.value.find(~/$opt.p/) { match -> println entry.value}
                }
```

I want to use the script from the command line in this way:

> groovy test -p pine_*a

And I expect that the result will be:

> pine___apple 
>   pineapple

I tried  these solutions and more, but nothing works:
`pine_*a`
`"pine_*a"`
`'pine_*a'`
`pine_\*a`
`'pine_\*a'`
`"pine_\*a"`
`pine_'\*'a`
`pine_"\*"a`
`pine_'\\*'a`
`pine_"\\*"a`

**Somebody knows how to solve this problem?
Thanks a lot!**

**EDIT:** 
I use: 
Groovy Version: 2.4.6 JVM: 1.7.0_45 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Windows 7 
 And I also use CliBuilder:

```
def cli = new CliBuilder()
        cli.with
        {
            p('pattern', args: 1, required: false)
        }   
        def opt = cli.parse(args)
```

Comment: Why do you think `opt.p` has your argument? Do you have some code in your groovy that sets this variable? Try printing `opt.p` to see what it contains.

Comment: If the value is unquoted, you are subject to the shell substituting filenames. For example: `touch pine_fooled_ya; groovy test -p pine_*a`. The safest way to pass a regular expression is in single quotes: `groovy test -p 'pine_*a'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following groovy script:

```
def map = [e:'pine___apple', f:'pineapple']
map.each { k, v ->
  v.find(~/${args[0]}/) { println "key: $k, value: $v -> ${v.find(args[0])}" }
}
```

prints the following on invocation:

```
$ groovy test.groovy pine_*a
Checking key: e, value: pine___apple -> pine___a
Checking key: f, value: pineapple -> pinea
```

or to exclude one of the map entries:

```
$ groovy test.groovy "pine_{1,9}a"
key: e, value: pine___apple -> pine___a
```

Not sure what the issue with your script is. Maybe the handling of opts.p like one of the comments suggests.

**edit 1**:

an alternative CliBuilder syntax to the one mentioned by Tim Yates in his answer:

```
def opt = new CliBuilder().with {
    p longOpt: 'pattern', args: 1
    parse(args)
}
```

**edit 2: solution**

as this is marked as the accepted answer, I will add what ended up being the solution here (I have a comment on this below, but comments are not immediately obvious when browsing for the solution).

This issue was caused by a bug in the windows groovy distribution `startgroovy.bat` file ([see separate stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749433/weird-behavior-of-windows-cmd-when-running-groovy)) which is used to launch groovy. The problem is with windows execution and parameter handling and it occurs before the groovy program even starts executing. There is a fair chance this has been fixed in later versions of groovy so it might be worth a try to upgrade to the latest version. If not, the answer in the above thread should make it possible to fix `startgroovy.bat`.

Comment: I tried your example and with the "pine_{1,9}a" arg i got the same result that you, but the pine_*a does not work for me. I still got a syntax error that i mentioned before. I really don't know what is the problem. I edited my question above, how i use CliBuilder and which groovy version work with. Any other idea what can be the problem ?

Comment: Could you try quoting as in `groovy test.groovy "ping_*a"`?

Comment: I tried. Still got a syntax error.  With the `test.groovy "pine_{1,9}a"` is working and got the same result as you, but with `groovy test.groovy "ping_*a"` got syntax error.

Comment: As per an earlier comment it might also be worth trying with single quotes depending on what operating system you are on. Could you also do a `entry -> def val = /$p.opt/;println "value is: '$val' ` before your `entry.value.find` so we can validate that the value of opt.p is what we think it is.

Comment: Oke. So the results:
`C:\Users>groovy test.groovy -p "pine_?"`
`value is: pine_?`
`pine___apple`
`value is: pine_?`
`pineapple`

`C:\Users>groovy test.groovy -p 'pine_?'`
`value is: 'pine_?'`
`value is: 'pine_?'`

`C:\Users>groovy test.groovy -p 'pine_*'`
`The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

`C:\Users>groovy test.groovy -p "pine_*"`
`The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

Comment: See [this other stackoverflow thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749433/weird-behavior-of-windows-cmd-when-running-groovy) on a bug in the windows `startgroovy.bat` file which is used to launch groovy. Your problem is with windows execution and parameter handling before the groovy program even starts executing. There is a fair chance this has been fixed in later versions of groovy so it might be worth a try to upgrade to the latest version. Or if not, read the answer in the above thread and see if you can fix `startgroovy.bat`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
 Now its working!  The change in startgroovy.bat was the solution.  I will try the latest version, maybe in that the problem is already fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Think it's the way you're capturing your `opt`

I assume you're using the CliBuilder

And I suspect you've missed the `args: 1` from the definition of the `p` parameter

```
def opt = new CliBuilder().with {
    it.p('pattern', args: 1)
    parse(args)
}  

def map1 = [e:'pine___apple', f:'pineapple']
map1.each { entry ->
    entry.value.find(~/$opt.p/) { match -> println entry.value}
}
```

Works as you describe it should for me...

Comment: Yes. I use CliBuilder, and i use args:1 too. I tried your example and don't work for me. I still got a syntax error that i mentioned before. I really don't know what is the problem. I edited my question above, how i use CliBuilder and which groovy version work with. Any other idea what can be the problem ?