# How can I use (^) caret in cmd arg (as a regex pattern) in groovy?

Tags: regex, groovy, command-line, arguments, caret

I've a groovy script with one argument. The argument has to be a regex pattern. I want to use a (^) in the argument, but I can't.

This is an example:

```
println "value is: $args"

def opt = new CliBuilder().with {
    p('pattern', args: 1)
    parse(args)
}  

def map1 = [e:'2001', f:'pine4', g:'almap']
def val = /$opt.p/

map1.each { entry ->
    entry.value.find(~/$opt.p/) { match -> println entry.value}
}
```

I want to get e.g. that element which contains only numbers, so
I use the script from the command line in this way:

```
groovy test -p ^[0-9]+$
```

This regex pattern means only numbers allowed. The ^ means matches anything beginning with a digit, and the $ means matches anything ending with a digit.
And *I expect* that the result will be:

```
2001
```

But because of the ^, the value that I got:

```
value is: [-p, [0-9]+$]
2001 
pine4
```

So you can see, that the ^ is not working, so it find all of the elements which ending with digit.

I tried to escape it (`\^`, `\\^`, `^^`), or quoting(`"^"`, `'^'`), and more solutions what i found, but nothing works.

I use:

- Groovy Version: 2.4.6
- JVM: 1.7.0_45
- Vendor: Oracle Corporation
- OS: Windows 7

I'm wondering that the solutions will be something like in this thread: [Weird behavior of windows CMD when running groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749433/weird-behavior-of-windows-cmd-when-running-groovy)

Comment: `^` is a keyword in windows cmd. It is an escaping character. Did you try escaping it like `^^`. `groovy test -p ^^[0-9]+$ `

Comment: Yes. Don't work. I know that eg. echo ^^ command will display the ^, but when i want to use it in the groovy script.. it doesn't work. I thought that maybe there is something in the startgroovy.bat what should i change. Like the linked page,

Comment: As I remember seeing somewhere, quadrupling caret(^^^^) may help you , since caret is also line continuation character

Comment: I saw somewhere too... but don't work. I can't escape in this way... something else will be the solutions....